# How does sudo decide whether a command is only executable by sudoers with ALL rights?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sudo

I just wondered why on a Debian system with sudo installed a default user can execute `ls` but not `ifconfig` since the binaries do have the same rights:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 114032 Jan 26  2013 /bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72296 Sep  7  2012 /sbin/ifconfig
```

So I suppose there must be some kind of database or policy that tells the system who's allowed to execute a command and who is not, but where do I find it? It can't be `/etc/sudoers` since in that file one only defines who is a root sudoer and who is not just like that:

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
john ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/userdel, /usr/bin/passwd
```

So `john` wouldn't be able to execute `/sbin/ifconfig`, but how does the system know he's not allowed?

Comment: because the app ifconfig attempts to do somthing it is forbidden to do by permissions (grab the network card object) and knows that when it itsn;t allowed to do that, it should print a pretty message saying 'use sudo darnit'.

Comment: Ok I see, but what system calls are those and what part of the kernel controls this? And why do they downvote me, it's a fair question I think.

Comment: `/sbin/` is not in the normal user's `$PATH`. At least on my Debian system, every user can call `/sbin/ifconfig` if they want, just not `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` has nothing to do with this little difference, the restriction is far closer to the kernel. You see, even though everyone has the right to execute the `/sbin/ifconfig` program, it does not mean that this program will have *sufficient permissions to do its job with normal user privileges.*

Basically, with the UNIX permissions set, you have the right to *create a process which executable code is `/sbin/ifconfig`'s*. And actually, no matter how `ls` and `ifconfig` behave afterwards, their processes **are** indeed spawned. However, `ifconfig` will exit prematurely because the privileges its given through the user executing it are not sufficient. Quoting Frank Thomas' comment:

> [it cannot] grab the network card object

**Note:** it might actually be possible for you to run `ifconfig --help` without privileges. Since this operation does not require using the network card, it won't fail nor require root privileges.

Now, if you want to know more specifically what operation has been denied to `ifconfig` with low privileges, you might want to give `strace` a try. Here's an example with `ls`.

> strace - trace system calls and signals

The [error code](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) for permission denied is 13 (`EACCES`). By using `strace` I can find out which system calls triggered `EACCES`:

```
$ strace ls ~ 2>&1 | grep EACCES
# No output, I can read my home directory just fine.
$ strace ls /root 2>&1 | grep EACCES
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/root", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

There, you can see that the `openat` system call failed. Indeed, as my current user, I have no right to read the `/root` directory, therefore the kernel yells at `ls` when it tries to get information about `/root`. When `ls` realises that `openat` failed and returned `EACCES`, it just tells me about it:

> ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied

Now, it's up to the program to tell the user when a system call fails. For instance, in C:

```
if((rootdir = opendir("/root")) == NULL){
    perror("myprogram");
    exit(1);
}
```

With low privileges, this will result it:

```
$ ./myprogram
myprogram: Permission denied
```

Now, if you run `strace /sbin/ifconfig`, you'll be able to find out which system call was denied to `ifconfig` when run as your user. Here is an example of me trying to bring the wireless interface down:

```
$ strace ifconfig wlan0 down 2>&1 | grep EPERM
ioctl(4, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="wlan0", ???}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

As you can see, the `ioctl` system call failed. In this case, the error call is `EPERM` (*1: Operation not permitted*). The `ifconfig` programs warns you about it in [its `setifflags` function](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?rev=1.169&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup):

```
// ...
if (ioctl(s, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifreq) == -1)
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "SIOCSIFFLAGS");
// ...
```